# Nativescript Mediafilepicker customizing DKImagePickerController UI

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm currently using Nativescript-Mediafilepicker plugin to handle image selection and also capturing image from camera in iOS. In ns mediafilepicker [docs](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker) , i can see that it is using DKImagePickerController native libraries to handle the image selection and In the DKImagePickerController [docs](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController), i can see there is an option to customize the UI (CustomUIDelegate).

Is there any possible way to do the same with Nativescript? I wish to customize the camera icon in the image picker gallery. In the DKImagePickerController CustomUIDelegate doc, i can see it is using DKAssetGroupDetailBaseCell to achieve the customization. How can i do this in Nativescript Angular?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: you cannot do it easily.

## Long Answer

You need to override methods since the plugin you are referring to does not expose APIs to modify the icon.

I have tried modifying it myself and I found out modifying the original plugin source code. I can give you hints on what you would have to do based on the understanding I have put in during the last few hours.

1. Create your custom MediaPicker

```
class MyMediaPicker extends Mediafilepicker {
...
}
```

2. Extend and copy the original `openImagePicker` method.
3. As you can see in [the original source code](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker/blob/4a3c38ecb06e0483ec49001727bc790e71c0ebf5/src/mediafilepicker.ios.ts#L51), you have access to the picker, but you need to create a custom iOS delegate that [handles the task of getting the `UIImage` for the camera...](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/e61f49bda664e41dafd3c06174ae0cd1eccda236/Example/DKImagePickerControllerDemo/CustomUIDelegate/CustomUIDelegate.swift#L86). This last task is painful, since the DK plugin guy created a custom class to refer to the Camera Cell that you now have to modify as well.

Once you modify (1) the picker plugin method, (2) the internal DK picker delegate, and (3) created a custom [CameraCell](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/e61f49bda664e41dafd3c06174ae0cd1eccda236/Sources/DKImagePickerController/View/Cell/DKAssetGroupDetailBaseCell.swift). You should be able to modify that camera icon.

---

Here are some useful links:

- https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker
- https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/e61f49bda664e41dafd3c06174ae0cd1eccda236/Sources/DKImagePickerController/DKImagePickerController.swift
- https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/e61f49bda664e41dafd3c06174ae0cd1eccda236/Sources/DKImagePickerController/Resource/DKImagePickerControllerResource.swift

Comment: I don't have a view on the original post, but in general it is wise to avoid building whole projects/plugins for bounty points - they can become increasingly futile exercises in free work.

Comment: I did not want to build a whole project, I honestly tried it with "a few lines", but the nature of the NativeScript plugin did not let me do it easily. But, since I wanted to learn, I kept on building more to "follow the rabbit hole". Do you mean that it is unwise to create a whole project from the start? If that's the case I agree, but I did not intend creating a whole project, I just stumbled upon a hard problem.

Comment: No, I mean that _some_ question authors on Stack Overflow can request whole projects while making little or no effort of their own, and some answer authors are generous to a fault, and end up working on someone else's project without remuneration. This may end up attracting the wrong kind of question author to Stack Overflow - the ones who are unwilling to learn things for themselves.

Comment: However, if you _enjoy_ following the rabbit hole, that's totally fine `:=)`.